# React-Native Context not yet populated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have a Context Provider that has a child component that consumes the Context. When I compile and test the app on mobile, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.isTrue')
```

I have created a minimum example in expo snack, and it seems to be working fine: https://snack.expo.io/H1XmyaWjr

When in React-Native on mobile, it seems like the parent has not yet populated the Context, and so the exception is raised because the object the child is referencing does not yet exist.

Is there a way to force the child to wait until the parent is mounted, or catch the exception and try to render again once the context is ready?

Comment: You should provide a reproductible example on RN. Please try with https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: What about doing a null check on the context value before accessing it? e.g. `t && t.isTrue`

Comment: @Poptocrack thanks for showing me this, have changed question with the snack expo link

Comment: @max23_ I think this is a great idea